# PHP static vs self variables and inheritance

Tags: php, oop, static

I have a PHP Model class that is extended by User and Post. They both share a constructor. I have a static variable for the 'schema' of each object so that I get the 'describe' from the database only once per object type, when the first is instantiated. I thought I could use static::_schema to reference the variable when each object is created, but if I create user and then post, post is referencing the user _schema variable. It does this if I use self:: OR static::. Am I wrong in understanding the difference? What am I doing wrong to get the outcome I want?

Below is the constructor function and getSchema function inside Model (the class Post and User both extend). But if I call getSchema on Post AFTER a User is created, it returns the User schema.

```
public function __construct($params = array())
{
    $this->_tableName = static::getTableName();
    $this->_className = static::getClassName();

    $this->getSchema();
}

public function getSchema()
{
    if (!static::$_schema) {
        $query = "DESCRIBE {$this->_tableName};";
        $sth = self::$db->prepare($query);
        $sth->execute(static::$bindings);
        $fields = $sth->fetchAll();

        foreach ($fields as $info) {
            static::$_schema[$info->Field] = array(
                'type' => $info->Type,
                'null' => $info->Null,
                'key' => $info->Key,
                'default' => $info->Default,
                'extra' => $info->Extra
            );
            if ($info->Key === 'PRI') {
                $this->_idField = $info->Field;
            }
        }
    }
    return static::$_schema;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that $_schema is only defined in User and not in Post so the same variable will always be used.

Comment: One way to solve it is to make _schema and array and you make the key get_class($this).

Comment: So it wouldn't matter if I used self or static in this scenario? I as under the assumption static was bound to the called class.

Comment: Your first statement is true. static just changes where it look up the thing you want. If you have a function in User and uses self:: it will look in User. If you use static it will first look in Post. But if _schema is not defined there it will fallback to User.

Comment: But User and Post both extend Model which is where the _schema variable and getSchema function is defined. So I assumed through inheritance that each would get its own instance of the schema variable, but I guess they are both just falling back to Model, which is being set by user's schema since that is what I instantiated first?

Comment: Sorry. Both Post and User will fallback to Model. _schema is only defined in Model so that is the one used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Late Static Binding

PHP's [Late Static Binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) is a pretty awesome concept when you get your head around it. In effect it allows you to code an object to handle the data contained within a child (extending) class. You can then change out the *child class* and as a result the parent (base) class will do something differently.

> In short, late static binding is an **inheritance-aware `self` call**. *[My quote, feel free to use it elsewhere]*

### The 'Model'

Just a quick recap. **The model is a layer**. It is the **layer** in MVC. Anyone who tells you that they have a "user model", or a "Post Model" does not know what they are talking about.

Feel free to re-cap on [how should a model be structured in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5864000/736809) and start referring to these (what should be) "dumb objects" as **Entities**. You have a `User` entity and a `Post` entity.

### Extending

When you extend an object, you are saying `ExtendingObject` **is-a** `ParentObject`. By extending `User` from `Model`, you are saying that the `User` **is-a** `Model`, which we have already established *by definition* is invalid. You are better having a generic `DB` object and passing that in via [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

### Constructors

Your constructors should have **no business logic**. When you create an object you are creating it in a specific state. This can be enforced by constructor parameters, typehints and exceptions for invalid scalar parameters. Once the object is created, *then* you run a method on it like `getSchema()`.

So, to re-cap:

- A `User` **is-not-a** `Model`
- The model is a layer, not an object
- Pass in other objects via dependency injection and adhere to [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)
- Your constructors should have no business logic

### LSB for aphillips

We're going to ignore the best practices listed above for educational purposes *only*, as you will of course re-factor this after learning how it works.

Your goal (from what I can gather): to have the correct table name available within the base class `Model`, *depending on which object is currently extending it* (`User` or `Post`).

```
abstract class Model
{
    /** Child classes MUST override this (you can enforce this if/however you like) **/
    const TABLE_NAME = "";

    public function __construct()
    {
        printf('Created table: %s', static::TABLE_NAME);
    }
}
```

So far, you have a `Model` object that can't be instantiated directly because it is abstract. Therefore, it must be extended to be used. Cool, let's create your POST object.

```
class Post extends Model
{
    const TABLE_NAME = "POST TABLE";
}
```

When you create the `Post` object, it'll use the inherited constructor from `Model`. In the `Model` constructor, it uses `static::` instead of `self::` to echo the table name. If it had used `self::`, it would have echoed 'Created table: '. Instead, because `static::`, the inheritance-aware version of `self::` is used, it uses the *inherited var* instead.

So the result of calling `$post = new Post;` will be "Created table: post".

Assuming you create a `User` object too:

```
class User extends Model
{
    const TABLE_NAME = 'User';
}
```

Each object will have it's own table name echoed when you create them:

```
$x = new User; // echoes User Table
$x = new Post; // echoes Post Table
```

### Conclusion

You don't have to do this with constants (although, I would). You can do it with class properties. But don't make them public (global mutable state is bad).

With the above information, you should be able to easily have a `getSchema()` method that uses `static::SCHEMA_NAME` in the `getSchema()` method for both `Post` and `User`.